# Beamer handouts and \alts and \temporals

Tags: beamer, handout

I'm creating handouts for my slides and would like the aterative text supplied to the `\alt` command to appear on the handout text (the `this` in the example below). Is there any way to configure beamer to do this? The default seems to be to put the default text on the handout slide.

I am aware that I can replace the `\alt` command with two `\only` commands, but that is not as neat as the `\alt` solution. I could also invert the overlay specification and swap the commands like so `\item \alt<1>{1}{2}`, but that is not a general solution as I would also want this behavior for the `\temporal` command. Is there any way to tell beamer to always put the latest version of the slide in the handout?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item    \alt<1>{not this}{this}
            \item<2> dummy
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item    \temporal<2>{not this}{not this either}{this}
            \item<3> dummy
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item    \alt<1|handout:0>{not this}{this}
            \item<2> dummy
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item    \temporal<2|handout:0>{not this}{not this either}{this}
            \item<3> dummy
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! Is there any way to make this default to reduce verbosity?

Comment: @nijoakim You don't want this to be the default, try `\item<2|handout:0> dummy`